# How to access all images within specific directory?

Tags: ios, swift

This is what i need to access:

[image]

I have a stickers for every language and I need to get an array of urls of these images. How can I do that for ezample for `en` directory?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, asset folder structure isn't preserved during compilation, so it doesn't matter how you organize them, they are stored flat in the app directory.

I suggest building a dictionary for your assets, and then fetching images that way, rather than using file structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [DirectoryEnumerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/directoryenumerator)

```
private func getStickersURL(for languageCode: String) -> [URL] {
    guard let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath else {
        return []
    }
    let dirPath = [resourcePath, "Stickers", languageCode].joined(separator: "\\")

    return FileManager.default
        .enumerator(atPath: dirPath)?
        .compactMap { $0 as? String }
        .compactMap {
            URL(
                fileURLWithPath: $0,
                relativeTo: URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath)
            ).absoluteURL
        } ?? []
}
```

Comment: Will it really work?;) I will award you if it is good working solution;)

Comment: I can't swear blind that it'll work but I keep fingers crossed :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work, because there is no `Stickers` directory at resourcePath like it is in project navigator;)

Comment: Mhm, looks like you need to provide more details then :)